# can't get flot-rails to work on ruby on rails 4.0.1. Error: undefined method `pie_chart'

Tags: ruby, charts, ruby-on-rails-4

In index.html.erb I added this line:

```
<%= pie_chart [{label: 'Hello World', data: 50}, {label: 'Foo', data: 25}, {label: 'Bar', data: 25}] %>
```

and this is the error message that I get:

```
undefined method `pie_chart' for #<#<Class:0x3fb9e50>:0x41fc508>
```

here is what I did:

I added gem `flot-rails` to gemfile
ran `bundle install` 
restarted the server
and added

```
//= require jquery.flot
//= require jquery.flot.resize
```

to `application.js`

Am I missing anything? I am very new to ruby on rails and any help is appreciated.

Comment: you include to module `ApplicationHelper ` constant `Flot` ?

Comment: No. This must be my problem. Can you please specify in which file I need to add it?

Answer (score 0):

in you `app/helpers/application_helper`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include Flot
end
```

if you use [this](https://github.com/Kjarrigan/flot-rails) gem.

Comment: actually I was trying to use this one - [link](https://github.com/Vasfed/flot-rails). I would not mind, however, to use the one you linked. I can't seem to install it. when I run bundle install I get some errors: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:88:in ``': No such file or directory - git clone "https://github.com/Kjarrigan/flot-rails.git" "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/flot-rails-0df769bc63e0c79f851d2d70d3f8cb108ec81166" --bare --no-hard
links (Errno::ENOENT)
 from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/l...

Comment: if you use this [gem](https://github.com/Vasfed/flot-rails) is `flot_plot` instead `pie_chart`